# Virtualbox выводит не то что я просил

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Вот код при выводе символа выводит либо пробел, либо три полоски, либо S все символы Английские

```
use16
start:
    mov cx, 7
    mov si, mesg
    cld
WriteLoop:
    lodsb
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h
loop WriteLoop
jmp $
times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
mesg db "Privet!"
```

Вот что выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **jmp start** ну зачем? Какой альтернативщик научил вас этому?

Comment: Попробуйте `push cs`, `pop ds` в начале кода добавить (после метки `start`). Ну и `jmp start` в данном случае лишний.

Comment: извините насчет jmp start у меня были переменные вверху я их сбросил вниз

Comment: Не помогло (...

Comment: Ну я тупанул дико, забыл написать `org 0x7C00`

Answer (score 1):

Извините забыл что нужно писать `org 0x7C00` после `use16` кому кому понадобится вот

```
use16
org 0x7C00
jmp start
;-----------
mesg db "Privet!"
;-----------
start:
    mov cx, 7
    mov si, mesg
    cld
WriteLoop:
    lodsb
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h
loop WriteLoop
jmp $
times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```